# Window 7 - Favorites folder

Tags: windows-7

I found my deleted favorites in hidden files under App Data, Local, Microsoft, Internet Explorer, Tiles. I want to delete the contents and the folder it's in. Will the Tiles folder reappear? If so, how do I get rid of it forever?

Comment: Yes; The *Tiles* folder will created again when you launched Internet Explorer.

Comment: Try the method in this link:https://appuals.com/deleted-favorites-keep-coming-back-on-internet-explorer/

Comment: @Ramhound, Thanks for answering my question. There are about 4,000 deleted favorites in the Tiles folder. I was shocked, or maybe not, that Microsoft would purposely keep this information. Now I know to delete the contents more often.

Comment: @Daisy Zhou, Thank you for the advice. I've never used any cloud service, but I did uninstall and reinstall IE even though I don't use it for anything other than the Favorites folder.

Comment: Your shocked that an application would generate files it needs to function?  Any application would do that just not a Microsoft application

Comment: @Ramhound, The favorites folder allows users to save web addresses. Deleted ones go to the recycle bin. When I delete an address I want it deleted, not saved in a hidden folder without even knowing it exists. That goes against privacy.